# Story about old man teleported to the future where earth is under heavy radiation

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I don't remember much about the story. I just remember that the main character is an ordinary old man that gets randomly teleported in the future, where most of Earth is contaminated with radiation. As far as I can remember, he doesn't find a way to go back his own time and some sort of war is happening. It's not much to go with but that's all I can remember.

After suggestion to had more that I can possibly remember, this what I can remember:
I think he had some telepathic powers or an experiment on him gave it to him. If I have something else that comes back, I will update this.

I probably read this book 15-16 years ago, but I'm sure it's older than that. The book looked old. The cover was all blue with maybe a castle on it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  As you mention, there's not a lot of detail to go on right now.  You should check out the [suggestions for writing a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any points that trigger some more memories.  Do you remember about how long ago you read this?

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the suggestion. I made some edits.

Comment: [Quite likely "Pebble in the Sky" by Isaac Asimov.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188535/science-fiction-short-story-beam-transporting-people-into-the-distant-future)  If so, then it is a duplicate.

Comment: @JRE that's what I was gonna suggest. The basic plot matches 'Pebble in the Sky'

Comment: @JRE It is. I did not find it. Vote to close then for duplicates. Thanks for finding it :)

Comment: @Rosme I've closed this as a duplicate. Thanks for letting us know.